# How to pull Zeit project

Tags: vercel

Small question from someone who is new to Zeit. 
Is there a way to pull my project?

I am working on different computers and I want to pull the project to the other so that I can work on it from both.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put your project on github and then you can clone it to other machines. You will need to install the now npm package globally on the other machine as well:

```
npm i -g now
```